# Encryption algorithm for PIC microcontroller

Tags: encryption, microcontroller, pic

I'm going to perform an encryption algorithm on the PIC18f2550 and I've chosen the DES and AES algorithms. I've never worked with a microcontroller before and am not sure how I would go about this.

Do I need to write a program for it or source it from somewhere?

If I want to write How to write a program for PIC with C and do you know of any educational materials for this?

Please let me know the best way to make a start on this.

Answer (score 2):

There are C compilers [here](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en_us/devtools/mplabxc/) (you need XC18) working with the [MPLAB X IDE](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx/).
[Here](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en547784#P76_1568) you can find the libraries. You need to download the "TCP/IP Stack" library. Inside this library you can find the C code for AES algorithm for several PIC series (PIC18 as well).

Comment: compiler xc8 or xc18?

Comment: XC8. _____________________